# Bing Maps when zoomed and scrolling, scrolls uncontrollably?

Tags: bing-maps

Not sure if anyone else is having this issue.  I have some remote users that I am attempting to troubleshoot an issue on their computer.  When they are using Bing Maps and the zoom to a location and attempt to scroll left or right the map scrolls uncontrollably to the left or right.  (it just continues to scroll vs scrolling just a little)

It seems to be specific to these users computers as from my computer and other home computers I have been unable to replicate this issue.

Has anyone else seen this, etc.?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem ended up being the video card in the users computer causing this issue.